# How to overwrite CSS

Tags: css, sapui5

I have a form that is automatically created from SAP NW BPM. This creates a SAP UI5 screen.   Normally the fields can be edited, but in this case I don't need the user to fill in any data.

I have a form element that looks like the following.

```
<f:FormElement label="{i18n>DO_OrgTransord.Street}">
 <f:fields>
  <m:Label text="{path:'Street'}" editable="false"/>
 </f:fields>
</f:FormElement>
```

The problem is that the label and the fields does not align as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sy048.png).

When I look at the corresponding [element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azoHT.pn) I see the label element has a style padding-top:1rem;. In IE/Edge if I remove this then it is shown as I would like to show the code.

I have tried with different forms of styling to make it look better, but it is not working. How can I the information on the label.

Comment: Please review your questions before posting, especially the wording and not added links make it hard to read.

Comment: Do you have access to the CSS file that goes with the page?

Answer (score 1):

In this case you should indeed use an Input or text element rather than a label.

By adding !important to a CSS style, it will overwrite the default CSS always.
See [!important rules at W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#important-rules)

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue fixed by adding

```
<form:Form editable="false">
```

It helped solve the issue with the elements being placed wrong. And since I did not need any input data here it seems okay.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I could use the sap.m.Test to view the data correct.

```
   <f:FormElement label="{i18n>DO_OrgTransord.VendorName}" >
       <f:fields>
            <m:Text text="{path:'VendorName'}"  xmlns:m="sap.m"  />
       </f:fields>
   </f:FormElement>
```